# Definition of mixing programming idioms?

Tags: terminology

Say I have class that is partially implemented as a static class and partially implemented as a singleton.

Besides "kludge" and "code-smell" (imo this is both) is there a more appropriate term for this type of mixing programming idioms?

Answer (score 7):

The time honored tradition is to name this type of error after the programmer that made it, and then refer to similar errors with that name until you find someone worse.  :-)

Comment: I like it (I am sure I can get some named after me).